# Is it possible to instantiate a function in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking a PHP script example that contains the mysqli extension. The code in question is as follows:

```
$conn = new mysqli("myServer", "myUser", "myPassword", "Northwind");
```

I'm confused as to wether this is a function or a class instance. If it is a function, is it possible to instantiate a function?

Comment: it is a class instance

Comment: [Here's](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) the construct call that these parameters are being passed to. "Returns an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server."

Comment: What would it mean to you if you could "instantiate" a function? What would be the result and what would you expect to be able to do with this instantiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What confuses you is the constructor.**

This is a special public function inside a class which get's called straight after an instance gets created.

`mysqli` in your case is a class, which has a constructor like this:

```
public function __construct($server, $user, $password, $dbname) {
 // do something
}
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

**Geekfact:**

You can somehow get an "instance" of a function by using closures. These arent real instances, just `callables`.

```
function createInstance() {
    return function($a, $b) {
        return $a + $b;
    };
}

$myIndependendFunction = createInstance();

echo $myIndependendFunction(3, 2); // prints 5
```

Comment: An instance is what you get when you use the word `new`. Right in that moment, the function `__construct()` of the class gets called (with the parameters used in `new MyClass($parameter)`). Don't worry about the functional form of mysqli. This is just there for legacy reason, to make it easier for people to migrate from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`. Stick with the objects in mysqli.

Comment: Confusion cleared with both of the links you added, you nailed it. I see now how its possible to pass parameters to a class instance. This was confusing me.

Comment: What threw me off is the fact that the instance has parameters. I also read that the mysqli extension was a function. So it makes a little more sense now. So an instance can take parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You declare *functions* and **use it**, you declare *objects* (mysqli object in this case) and you **instantiate it**.

You can read the manual.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score -2):

If you want to contain your instantiation logic in one place you could wrap your current code within a function and return the ready to use mysqli class?

Example:

```
<?php

function getMysqliConnection(){
    return new mysqli("myServer", "myUser", "myPassword", "Northwind");    
}

$conn = getMysqliConnection();
```

Comment: *your, you're = you are. `If you want to contain you are instantiation logic` makes no sense.